# Powershell SQL attach database with multiple database files

Tags: sql, database, powershell, smo

I've created a Powershell script using SMO for detaching a database and copy the files to a new location.

I've detached the database with multiple database files (one .mdf file and 4 .ndf files), copied them to the new location and need to attach the database including the four .ndf files. How do I change the ndf file path to the new location? Is this done while running the $sqlSrv.AttachDatabase command or afterwards? And how?

Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you successfully attached the database with `Server.AttachDatabase`, including the .ndf files, then they already have the correct location. If for whatever reason you wanted to move them, you can simply detach the database, move the files and re-attach it. It's only when restoring a database that you need to specify new locations for files if the defaults are wrong.

Comment: The problem was, when I had moved all the files to the new location and attached the mdf file together the the ldf file - if the database had any ndf files, these ndf file paths still pointed to the old location. However I solved this by doing an Invoke-SqlCmd to alter the database with the new file paths.